# How to search array of objects and push new value in array Angular 8

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

I have two different response from API. Below response contain lineId and Name.

```
this.lines = [
    {      
        lineId: "R_X002_ACCESS"
        localName: "ACCESS"
        name: "ACCESS"
    },
    {      
        lineId: "R_X00R_X002_BIB2_ACCESS"
        localName: "BIB"
        name: "BIB"
    },
    {      
        lineId: "R_X002_KNORR"
        localName: "Knorr"
        name: "Knorr"
    },
     {      
        lineId: "R_X002_POWDER"
        localName: "Powder"
        name: "Powder"
    },
];
```

**This response is for processData function, Here i wanted to search name from `this.lines` api response based on lineId of item object and if matches then need to push Name**

```
item = {
lineId: "R_X002_POWDER"
},
{
lineId: "R_X00R_X002_BIB2_ACCESS,R_X002_ACCESS"
},
{
lineId: "R_X002_POWDER"
};
```

Now in below code , i am searching name based on lineId from this.lines api response
and if it matches then trying to push inside plist array.

Below is my code, here i am passing api response and preparing array based on some condition.

I tried below code inside **processData function**, but it is not working for comma seprated valuesand also not pushing to  proper plist array.

```
var lineName = this.lines.filter(function(line) {
        if(line.lineId === item.lineId){
         return line.name;
        }
      });




processData(data: any) {
    let mappedData = [];
    for(const item of data){
      console.log(item,"item");
      var lineName = this.lines.filter(function(line) {
        if(line.lineId === item.lineId){
         return line.name;
        }
      });
      const mitem = mappedData.find(obj => obj.makeLineName == item.makeLineName);
      if(mitem){
        mitem['plist'].push(item);
      } else {
        let newItem = item;
        newItem['plist'] = [ item ];
        mappedData.push(newItem);
      }
    }
    return mappedData;
  }
```

**Expected output**

```
 lineId: "R_X002_POWDER",
     name: "Powder"
    },
    {
    lineId: "R_X00R_X002_BIB2_ACCESS,R_X002_ACCESS",
     name: "BIB","ACCESS"
    },
    {
    lineId: "R_X002_KNORR",
     name: "Knorr"
    };
```

Comment: Please , also fix the type of `item` and `expected output`. I think they should be array(s) too.

Answer (score 0):

I think because of lineId returned to you, instead of checking lineId equality you should check if the incoming lineId includes your lineId. 
in your code: instead of `line.lineId === item.lineId`
 check this: `(item.lineId).includes(line.lineId)`

maybe it works...

Comment: But how i will push this var lineName into  mitem['plist'] and newItem['plist'] array ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you(`mapNames` function)...

```js
const lines = [
    {
        lineId: "R_X002_ACCESS",
        localName: "ACCESS",
        name: "ACCESS"
    },
    {
        lineId: "R_X00R_X002_BIB2_ACCESS",
        localName: "BIB",
        name: "BIB"
    },
    {
        lineId: "R_X002_KNORR",
        localName: "Knorr",
        name: "Knorr"
    },
    {
        lineId: "R_X002_POWDER",
        localName: "Powder",
        name: "Powder"
    },
];

const items = [
    {
        lineId: "R_X002_POWDER"
    },
    {
        lineId: "R_X00R_X002_BIB2_ACCESS,R_X002_ACCESS"
    },
    {
        lineId: "R_X002_POWDER"
    }
];

function mapNames(lines, items) {
    const mappedLines = {};
    
    lines.forEach(lineItem => {
        if (!mappedLines[lineItem.lineId]) {
            mappedLines[lineItem.lineId] = lineItem;
        }
    });
    
    const mappedItems = items
        .map(item => {
        return {
            lineId: item.lineId,
            name: item.lineId.split(",")
                .map(lineItem => mappedLines[lineItem].name || "")
                .filter(x => x)
                .join(",")
        };
    });
    return mappedItems;
}

console.log("Mapped Names:\n", mapNames(lines, items));
```

Comment: But how i will push this var lineName into mitem['plist'] and newItem['plist'] array ?

Comment: I have added beloe code inside my foreach and its working fine, now i just want how to push this into plist array.

Comment: var lineName = this.lines.filter(function (line) {
        if ((item.lineId).includes(line.lineId)) {
          return line.name;
        }
      });

Comment: The function `mappedNames` already generates the expected output., and is an array... Are you expecting it to be something else?

Comment: Plz chk my processData function i want your output to be merge in mitem['plist'] and newItem['plist'] as i am processing other data to inside same function and pushing into plist array only.

Comment: I want to call this function inside processData function and return output to be merge in same mitem['plist'] variable. I want all return object to be merge inside plist array only

Comment: what is `data` in `processData`? Is it the one returned by the function that I have written?

Comment: Also, what is the output generated by `processData`?

Comment: Also, you are calculating `lineName` inside `processData`, but not using it anywhere.

Comment: what is the output generated by `processData`? Is it the same as you have outlined in `expected output`?

Comment: can you give an example how does it look like after pushing this data(expected output) into `plist`?

Comment: can you please add this `arrayOne` example, before adding to `plist` and after adding into `plist`. I can try to edit the answer for you with an example...

Comment: But `makeLineName` has a value "RED", how do you associate it with array of `lines` or with the `expected output`?

Comment: Everything isnworking fine in old code, jst wanted to search line name based on lineId and result will push into plist array thats simple. No need to go for makeLineName. I told u jst to understand what i am doing in processData function

Comment: You only search this.Lines array based on lineId of foreach inside preocessData function and if name you got then merge this name with old plist data